# Share documents in SBS 2008

Tags: file-sharing, windows-sbs, document-management

Does Windows Small Business Server 2008 has a solution to share (create, update, save) local documents via http? Something like google docs..

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SBS includes Sharepoint (Windows Sharepoint Services - WSS) which can do basic document sharing over HTTP.

More info from TechNet:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/bb684453

Comment: Umm. SBS includes IIS7, which is capable of "sharing" via [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) - or did he ask for a web interface like in [Office Web Apps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Web_Apps)?

Comment: @syneticon-dj He asked for something `"like google docs"`. Sharepoint's inline document editor is just that.

Comment: Google docs has many aspects - including storage. This is why I mentioned Office Web Apps, which resemble Google Docs' editors feature set. Sharepoint's editor is only capable of editing HTML-style content sites and is rather dumb.